# How to find out why my server has been blocked

Tags: socrata, soda

I have an application token. According to documentation

> If you are throttled for any reason, you will receive a status code
>   429 response.

I have received no errors that I am being throttled. Sending requests from other servers are accepted just not the one that has been working fine up until today. What needs to be done to unblock my server and/or prevent it from reoccurring?

Comment: [Read the docs](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/transforms/http_get.html)? >> `This call is subject to a rate limit of 2 requests per second.`

Comment: Many times when you are rate-limited by a service, it will add a header with details to accompany the 429. Do not look at just the status code, but the whole response header.

Comment: Also recommend that you contact support@socrata.com and describe your application name (not the token), the query, and that you've received the error.